# How do you get full TFS Iteration details in the API

Tags: c#, tfs, iteration, workitem

I am am trying to scan TFS for `WorkItems` that have ever been in a sprint.
Now through normal TFS queries you can search on `Iteration Id` and use the `Was Ever` operator, but to get that ID you must have a known `WorkItem` that has lived there at some point, currently or in its history.

I've been able to assemble where or not a path is a backlog or sprint iteration, start ans stop dates of those iterations, but not the ID

Ideally i would like to either supply its `Guid` or its path to get its ID,
but no where can I get the simple Integer ID for the

Currently I get my iteration tree with the following:

```
public static IterationTreeItem GetIterationTree()
{
    var structures = TfsShared.Instance.CommonStructureService.ListStructures(TfsShared.Instance.ProjectInfo.Uri);
    var iterationNode = structures.First(_ => _.Name == "Iteration");

    var rawIterationTree = TfsShared.Instance.CommonStructureService.GetNodesXml(new[] { iterationNode.Uri }, true);
    var iterationTree = rawIterationTree.FirstChild;

    var teams = TfsShared.Instance.AllTeams.ToList();

    var configs = TfsShared.Instance.TeamSettingsConfigurationService
                     .GetTeamConfigurations(teams.Select(_ => _.Identity)
                                                 .Select(_ => _.TeamFoundationId));

    var backLogPaths = configs.Select(_ => _.TeamSettings.BacklogIterationPath)
                                  .OrderBy(_ => _)
                                  .Distinct()
                                  .ToArray();

    var fullTree = new IterationTreeItem(iterationTree);

    var iterationList = IterationTreeItem.Flatten(fullTree).ToList();

    IterationTreeItem.SetBackLogsOrSprints(iterationList, backLogPaths);
    return fullTree;
}
```

The structure I get back from ICommonStructureServices looks like, but contains many more teams and sprints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Nodes xmlns="">
    <Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/43eaa612-c4b1-4043-bbd6-62f56387a7c8" Name="Iteration" Path="\coresystems\Iteration" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/4f1ea3c6-5306-4671-b806-8c2df536d218" StructureType="ProjectLifecycle">
        <Children>
            <Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/6c123a22-c647-489a-a683-ca6a5bb19f92" Name="Team01" ParentID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/43eaa612-c4b1-4043-bbd6-62f56387a7c8" Path="\coresystems\Iteration\Team01" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/4f1ea3c6-5306-4671-b806-8c2df536d218" StructureType="ProjectLifecycle">
                <Children>
                    <Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/27efc3cf-270f-463b-9aec-1569d7eaec8a" Name="Sprint1" ParentID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/6c123a22-c647-489a-a683-ca6a5bb19f92" Path="\coresystems\Iteration\Team01\Sprint1" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/4f1ea3c6-5306-4671-b806-8c2df536d218" StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" />
                    <Node NodeID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/987b4bae-83ea-4f6f-beba-697ab8bb039f" Name="Sprint2" ParentID="vstfs:///Classification/Node/6c123a22-c647-489a-a683-ca6a5bb19f92" Path="\coresystems\Iteration\Team01\Sprint2" ProjectID="vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/4f1ea3c6-5306-4671-b806-8c2df536d218" StructureType="ProjectLifecycle" />
                </Children>
            </Node>
        </Children>
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

Now the IterationTreeItem Class looks like the following:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{CleanIterationPath,nq}")]
public class IterationTreeItem
{
    private readonly List<IterationTreeItem> _children = new List<IterationTreeItem>();

    public IterationTreeItem(XmlNode node)
    {
        if (node != null)
        {
            XmlNode = node;

            var nodeId = GetNodeId(node);

            NodeInfo = TfsShared.Instance.CommonStructureService.GetNode(nodeId);
            if (node.FirstChild != null)
            {
                var children = node.FirstChild.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>()
                                   .Select(_ => new IterationTreeItem(_, this))
                                   .ToArray();

                Children.AddRange(children);
            }
        }
    }

    private IterationTreeItem(XmlNode node, IterationTreeItem parent)
        : this(node)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public List<IterationTreeItem> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

    public string CleanBacklogPath
    {
        get
        {
            var parts = CleanIterationPath.Split('\\').ToArray();
            return string.Join("\\", parts.Take(Math.Max(parts.Length - 1, 1)));
        }
    }

    public string CleanIterationPath
    {
        get
        {
            if (NodeInfo != null)
            {
                var notStartedWithSlashes = NodeInfo.Path.Substring(1);
                return notStartedWithSlashes.Replace("\\Iteration", string.Empty);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
    public bool? IsProductBackLogIteration { get; private set; }

    public bool? IsSprintIteration { get; private set; }

    public NodeInfo NodeInfo { get; private set; }

    public IterationTreeItem Parent { get; private set; }

    public XmlNode XmlNode { get; private set; }

    public static IEnumerable<IterationTreeItem> Flatten(IterationTreeItem item)
    {
        yield return item;
        foreach (var childChild in item.Children.SelectMany(Flatten))
        {
            yield return childChild;
        }
    }

    public static void SetBackLogsOrSprints(IEnumerable<IterationTreeItem> items, IEnumerable<string> knownBacklogs)
    {
        var backLogs = knownBacklogs as List<string> ?? knownBacklogs.ToList();
        foreach (var iterationTreeItem in items)
        {
            if (backLogs.Any(_ => _ == iterationTreeItem.CleanIterationPath))
            {
                iterationTreeItem.IsProductBackLogIteration = true;
                iterationTreeItem.IsSprintIteration = false;
            }
            else
            {
                iterationTreeItem.IsProductBackLogIteration = false;
                iterationTreeItem.IsSprintIteration = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetNodeId(XmlNode node)
    {
        if (node.Attributes != null)
        {
            var otherNodeId = node.Attributes.OfType<XmlAttribute>().First(_ => _.Name == "NodeID").Value;
            return otherNodeId;
        }

        var xml = node.OuterXml;
        const string first = "NodeID=\"";
        var start = xml.IndexOf(first, StringComparison.Ordinal) + first.Length;
        var end = xml.IndexOf("\"", start, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        return xml.Substring(start, (end - start));
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding IterationID in TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156649/finding-iterationid-in-tfs)

Comment: You could just get the iteration root nodes and then their children.  Compare node.Path and return node.Id when it matches. [var rootNodeCollection = workItemStore.Projects["ProjectName"].IterationRootNodes;].  Another way would be to return the list of Work Items you want to check in a query and then walk their revision history.  Might be slower I guess if you have a lot of items to check.    I can knock up a sample if no one else has a better answer

Comment: @rerwinRR you gave me the right starting point. i technically when up to the highest node with `IterationRootNodes.OfType<Node>().First().ParentNode` so i could match all node but you pointed me at the right path. the individual `Node` class for this instance does contain the expected ID I'm looking for. if you officially make an answer i'll give you the credit