# Which is the Iteration ID?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

For on-premise TFS 2015:

When I use the Rest API to get iteration ids for a team the ids appear to be a GUID (e.g. "d682cb38-75f3-485d-a238-7da5f7a41b9e").

I need to find work items for that iteration, but when I use WIQL to query `[System.IterationsId]` it comes back as an integer (e.g. 9424).

How would I find work items for an iteration?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you kindly provide a little more context about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding IterationID in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156649/finding-iterationid-in-tfs)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - I'm not sure it is a dupe, that's for the SOAP API, the Rest API might is something different.

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to gather the info required to generate an excel report that shows the same results as the bar graph for backlog shows. That report appears to find the hours per day capacity for each team member, and compare them to the remaining hours of work. I believe I have 1 of the 2 pieces of info I need. 1. See next comment for continuation.

Comment: I'm getting the capacity for an iteration using the API GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/capacities?api-version=4.1. So now I need to get the remaining hours for each team member for that iteration. In trying to do that I noticed that when I used the API to get capacities i sent the iteration id in what appeared to be a GUID. However when I used WIQL to list work items the [System.IterationId] appeared as an int e.g. 2, 3456 etc. Are these not the same fields?